# jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function while using WooCommerce predictive search plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When I am activating the WooCommerce predictive search plugins, we get below error in jQuery.

> jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function
>
> jQuery("#pp_course_3").autocomplete(urls, {

If I deactivate the woocommerce predictive search plugins then it works correctly.

Comment: seems like jquery conflict issue , make sure that woocommerce predictive search is not loading another jquery instance

Comment: I have corrected the formatting of the error messages. Code block like formatting is not the correct choice. I have also made some grammar corrections to the content.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?